# Unable to create folder on android 6.0.1

Tags: android, cordova

I am using official [file API Plugin](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file)
on my cordova application, where it work fine on my android devices except who has  **Android 6.0.1**.

It's unable to create directory, and throw error number **2** which is [SECURITY_ERR](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file#list-of-error-codes-and-meanings)

**JS code:**

```
  window.requestFileSystem = window.requestFileSystem || window.webkitRequestFileSystem;
        window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, function (response) {
            response.root.getDirectory("folderNamexxx", {create: true, exclusive: false}, function () {
                alert("success");
            }, function (e) {
                alert(JSON.stringify(e));//error fired here
            });
        }, function (e) {
            alert("error");
        });
```

**Androidmanifest.xml:**

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<permission android:name="${applicationId}.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<uses-permission android:name="${applicationId}.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

config.xml:

```
 <preference name="AndroidPersistentFileLocation" value="Compatibility" />
```

Comment: Are you using latest file plugin(4.2.0)? I guess not. Try using latest file plugin where the run time permission handling is already handled.

Comment: @Gandhi, yes i am using this version 4.2.0, but the weird thing is that it work fine on some other devices having the same android version 6.0.1.

Comment: In that case you may have to check the settings in their individual device. May be some permission settings would have got reviked manually. Check out this link - http://www.howtogeek.com/230683/how-to-manage-app-permissions-on-android-6.0/

Comment: @Gandhi, thank you i will check it with the customer, the i will update the comment

Comment: You are welcome.Keep me posted.Good luck

Comment: @Gandhi,Thank you. you are right, granting permission from settings solved the issue.

Comment: Posted the same as answer. Please accept if useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set run time permission before creating any folder ,(Read and write external storage) Please Follow This link have example hot to set run time permission [Link](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html)

If you don't want to set Runtime permission and OK with api level 22 than change yore target sdk to 22

Answer (score 1):

Ensure to use latest cordova file plugin (4.2.0). Also ensure to have proper permission settings in device, you will be good to go. Check out this link for more [info](http://www.howtogeek.com/230683/how-to-manage-app-permissions-on-android-6.0/).